# How to write image in wsq format?

Tags: java, image

I am using the following code:

```
OutputStream outputfile = new FileOutputStream("resource/LeftIndexSegmentMy.WSQ");
ImageIO.write(subImage,"WSQ", outputfile);
```

However, the resulting file is empty. No image is there.

So, how do I write an image in the [WSQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_scalar_quantization) format?

Comment: OutputStream = new FileOutputStream ??

Comment: You need to look for a WSQ Encoder. The github project [JMRTD](https://github.com/E3V3A/JMRTD/blob/master/wsq_imageio/src/org/jnbis/WSQEncoder.java) wrote an encode based on java Bitmap objects. It your snippted, it is not clear what the source of your subImage is

Comment: Hi, Please refer below comment and give me some solution, still I am facing problem

Comment: Hi, any solution for me

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? Maybe create a full [mcve]. Also, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. **Edit** your question instead of posting non-answers as answers. It sounds like you are not familiar with what Stackoverflow is and what not.